# Is a pig-shaped money box haram?

Tags: halal-haram, image, pork

Today I went into store and saw a very cute and big money box, but it was a pig shaped money box. My wife told me not to buy it, as its a pig shaped? I understand she is more religious than me but isn't it a overkill of telling someone you can't have a money box because it shape is in pig form or wearing a shirt that have pig on it. Do we Muslims push our boundaries?

Comment: It is indeed an "overkill". Consumption of pig is not allowed but I don't know how that extends to a plastic money box. Pigs are actually given a bad rap in the Islamic community. They are not the disgusting animals that we are lead to believe from birth (or atleast I was, and its common in the indopak communities).

Comment: The issue will then remain with, whether keeping images of animals are allowed or not? (In your case is a 3D image)

Comment: Pigs are only haraam for eating and nothing else.

Answer (score 1):

Pigs are haram to eat ([Qur'an 2:173](https://quran.com/2/173)) and are regarded as unclean (see [What things are considered najis in fiqh?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/46819/17163)).  However, a piggy bank is not a pig.

Piggy banks could reasonably be regarded as haram due to being a three-dimensional statue of a living being:

> No doubt making statues of living beings is forbidden according to the consensus of Muslim scholars.
>   <sub>[IslamWeb](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=87462)</sub>

However, it might be an exception to this rule if it's a children's toy (see a Qibla.com fatwa via [IslmaQA.org](https://islamqa.org/shafii/qibla-shafii/33052): *Children's toys are not considered statues and it is not haram to buy or acquire them.*).

Comment: That’s right but, they have been made for the purpose to put money inside it and not for fun or for worship.

Answer (score -1):

Salaam, Peace be apon you

Yes, it is fine. Buying something a pig product in it is haram, but buying a something with an image of a pig or the shape of a pig on or in it is not haram. I think that would be an overkill. But it is not recommended to have a sculpture of a living thing in your house.

i hope this will be helpful (:

Answer (score -1):

If it resembles something haram then I may think that it may be haram (Allahoa3lam). If you don't have it it's better, at least you have no risk of being sinful. Find a other-shaped-money box.

Answer (score -2):

Actually prior to this thought of her, I would have bought it. Yet now I believe that if there are alternatives then why not go for them? Its not haram to use it, though I would go for it as a last resort.

Pigs are filthy animals... and eating pork affects غیره (~jelousy+protection of men for their Maharim)...so any sort of eating pork or eating from dishes/kitchens that use pork is highly prohibited... and therefore this animal is worthy of such hatred...and to a very very very limited extent it can be applied for a piggy bank so that our children would understand Islam's dislike for pigs. Again I'd go for a piggy bank but as a last resort... why not Islamitize piggy banks for our own culture & religion?

Comment: The plastic box is not haram so there is no reason to stay away from it. Secondly, if you are going to claim that pigs are filthy animals then you need to show some evidence for it. Pigs are far from being "filthy" animals. There is absolutely no reason that the animal is "worthy" of such hatred, especially from a point of view of Islam which begs love and kindness to all animals.

Comment: Did I say its Haram? Kindness to animal is good,even for pigs... yet that doesn't disqualify the animal itself from being filthy...or if it being filthy meaning that we should harm it!
Pigs are filthy because they eat  their own excrement and is the ONLY animal that allows other pigs to have sex with its mate with no protection while other animals protect their mate from others.The latter is less known.
Though maybe doing those are OK to some people nowadays in the west known as swinging...

Comment: Pigs do not eat their own excrement if left in their natural habitat. They only do so under human farming conditions but then this is also the case for many animals (even those that are halal for us). Chicken for example will also eat feces to get at seeds and other foods. I don't know about their reproductive behaviour, but I am fairly certain that, again, its applicable to other halal animals as well. In fact pigs are highly social and intelligent animals. We can take this to chat if you wish.

Comment: @masfenix neither one of us is an expert in this regard and its beyond the question's scope. But I just want to know what is your take on why then pork is Haram...

Comment: You don't need to be an expert to learn simple behaviour of pigs. A Wikipedia article + its references are sufficient.  A scientific understanding is that pigs and humans are biologically very similar and that deadly human diseases can easily be passed through pigs. It may be one reason that pigs are haram so they do not stay in the same vicinity as humans but there isn't sufficient evidence that disease rates are high near a pig pen. Also, its said that human flesh tastes very similar of that to pork. Youtube "Why Heaven Hates Ham" a paragraph by Chris Hitchens;