# is pus and blood najis

Tags: wudu, najis

I bursted a pimple on my thigh and rubbed on that pus and blood till the blood and pus were not visible. Then wore the pant and undergarments.

Do my clothes and pants become najis of small amount of left over blood and pus if it sticks to the clothes?

And if I burst a pimple and blood and pus comes out of the pimple, does it invalidate my wudu?

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. For further information on our site and the stack exchange model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0) for SE to distribute that content. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/295232)?

Comment: how to rollback to first time post i dont have the text written first time

Answer (score 2):

Note that blood and pus are considered as najis (ritually unclean)by most scholars (See for example [What items are considered najis in fiqh?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/46819/what-things-are-considered-najis-in-fiqh)). Ibn Taymiyyah is among those few who considered at least pus as tahir (ritually clean). So praying with one or both of them on the body or clothes may make a prayer invalid.

Nevertheless as it is the case with water a large amount of tahir/clean material wipes away a small amount of najassa (unclean material) scholars had different opinions on the amount or dimension that limits what is considered as small amount of blood or pus:
As for the hanafis they said it is an amount that is equal or smaller than a Dirham (a known measurement/coin), the malikis considered what is below the dimension of a Dirham as tahir (in case of blood only). The shafi'is based the small amount on what is known as such by habit العُرف this would apply to pus too in the maliki school.

The above is a summary of the quotes from the fatwa islamweb #[18639](https://www.islamweb.net/ar/fatwa/18639) on blood and this one on pus #[156431](http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=156431) -both in Arabic-(I didn't quote the hanbali opinion so far as I found an English quote). More details on the opinions on pus can be found in the fatwa islamweb #[128250](http://www.islamweb.net/fatwa/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&lang=A&Id=128250) -in Arabic-.
Here a quote from hanbali book:

> It says in al-Mughni (1/409):
> If he prays and there is some impurity on his garment, even if it is a little, he should repeat his prayer, unless it is a small amount of blood or pus, that one would not think of as anything significant. (Source islamqa #[163819](https://islamqa.info/en/163819))

all these verdicts are based on ahadith such as:

> One of us would have a shirt in which she would menstruate and in it she became sexually defiled. Then if she ever saw any drop of blood in it, she would rub it off by applying her saliva. (See for example in [Sunan abi Dawod](https://sunnah.com/abudawud/1/364))

So if the amount of blood pus on your clothes was small your prayers were valid else not.

Note that if blood or pus came out of one of the two usual body "outputs" it is certainly invalidating wudu' by all four madhhabs. Else there's a dispute among scholars, but for example islamweb considers the view that it doesn't invalidate the wudu' as stronger.

Refreshing wudu' nevertheless is recommended and one could say required, when you intend to pray as you would stay in front of your Creator and should stand in front of him in the best and cleanest manner.

In this fatwa on islamqa #[243145](https://islamqa.info/ar/243145) the dimension of this Dirham is discussed and it diameter is approximately 3 cm (In fact it was compared to silver Riyal coin minted during the reign of the saudi King Abdul Aziz, which had a diameter of 37mm).