# Water dripping out of penis after washing it

Tags: wudu

When I wash my private part (male) for wudu with water and when I later on come out of the bathroom a small amount of clear liquid starts to come out of my penis. I’m not sure if it is urine or if it is just water that got trapped inside the penis. When this happens I always have to perform wudu again. Can someone please tell me if my wudu is still valid if this ever happens?

Comment: This is covered in my answer on [Does using urinals make bathing compulsory?](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/51446/does-using-urinals-make-bathing-compulsory/51452#51452)